# How to avoid overfull \hbox warning when using tabularx with \textwidth?

Tags: koma-script, warnings, tabularx, parskip

## Question

How do I avoid the warning

> Overfull \hbox (10.95003pt too wide) in paragraph at lines [...]

produced by the following document?

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

%\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
  \toprule
  Test  & Test
  \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
%\end{center}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The output looks okay:

[image: output]

## Explanation

From the KOMA script manual `scrguide.pdf`:

> **`half`**
>   Absätze werden durch einen vertikalen Abstand von einer halben Zeile gekennzeichnet. Absatzenden durch einen Leerraum von mind. ein Geviert (1em) der normalen Schrift am Ende gekennzeichnet.

Using `\textwidth` contradicts this, hence the warning.

> **`half-`**
>   Absätze werden durch einen vertikalen Abstand von einer halben Zeile gekennzeichnet. Absatzenden werden nicht gekennzeichnet.

This avoids the warning.

## Using `center` environment

Wrapping the `tabularx` in `\begin{center}...\end{center}` seems to work. Why? And is this a good idea? How do I avoid the additional vertical spacing?

Answer:

As egreg explained,
in the center environment, \parfillskip is set to zero.

## Other ideas

The usual suggestion of adding `\noindent` has no effect. There is no indentation when using `parskip=half`. (The problem is at the end of the line, see the answers.)

Writing `{.97\textwidth}` is of course not a solution.

Using `{@{}XX@{}}` does not get rid of the warning.

Comment: Try adjusting with `\textwidth-2\tabcolsep`. `\showthe\tabcolsep` yields `\tabcolsep=6pt` which is sufficient for your use case. Not sure if it's a best practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `parskip=half` option sets a parfillskip with a nonzero natural width (precisely to one em). It does so in order to avoid that a paragraph ends flush with the right margin, but, of course, this disallows an object fills a line by itself.

The correct way of solving this is not using a nonzero parskip under any circumstance, except, perhaps, business letters. Of course this recommendation reflects my opinion, that, however, I share with several great typographers.

If you really want to use this abominable `;-)` typesetting style, just locally set `\parfillskip` to zero:

```
\documentclass[draft,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
  \toprule
  Test  & Test
  \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}{\parfillskip=0pt\par}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation and the "local" fix. I still do not understand why the center environment, which uses the same parskip, also removes the warning.

Comment: @Thomas In the `center` environment, `\parfillskip` is set to zero.

Comment: This seems to be a good idea. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

use `half-` (minus!):

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
```

See the documentation for the meaning of `half-`, `half`, `half+`, and `half*`

Comment: Of course, thank you! Definitely the shortest correct answer giving the reason for the problem and a way to fix it. One has to change a global option, but in my case, this is not a problem. Note that - is a hyphen.

Comment: Your global option `half` is _wrong_, if you do not want a space of 1em at the end of a paragraph.

Comment: You are of course right. One might or might not want to have this space at the end of paragraphs. At the end of  tabularx-"paragraphs", I do not want it. As you suggested, half- removes all warnings in a clean KOMA-ish way.

Comment: @Thomas Well, you can always set this option “locally”.